# Deployed code doesn't work, but It does locally

Tags: java, rest, google-app-engine, servlets

I'm building a rest service to upload files throught a post request.
I have two servlets, first takes the request and changes the URI in order to call a blob key and forwards the request to the servlet that is going to save the file.

My servlets look like this:

```
uploadfiles.java

    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package costache.examproject;

import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author Gabriel
 */
public class uploadfiles extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

            String bloblink = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload");

            String[] linkcut = bloblink.split("_ah");
            String newUri = "_ah" + linkcut[1];
            request.getRequestDispatcher(newUri).forward(request, response);
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

upload.java

```
package costache.examproject;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory;

public class upload extends HttpServlet {
    private BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
        List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobs.get("myFile");

        if (blobKeys == null || blobKeys.isEmpty()) {
            res.sendRedirect("/");
        } else {
            res.sendRedirect("/serve?blob-key=" + blobKeys.get(0).getKeyString());
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to send the file throught a post, it works locally (Debugger triggers every point of both servlets), but once deployed on the GAE it doesn't, it gives back "Error: Not Found"

Form HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>

        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="windows-1252">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>


        <form action="uploadfiles" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            Nome: <input id="n" type="text" name="foo">
            Consumer: <input id="c" type="text" name="consumer">
            Uploader: <input id="u" type="text" name="uploader">
            Contenuto: <input id="co" type="file" name="myFile">
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>examproject</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>filters.OfyStarter</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>registrazione</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>costache.examproject.registrazione</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>costache.examproject.login</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>upload</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>costache.examproject.upload</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>serve</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>costache.examproject.serve</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>caricafile</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>costache.examproject.caricafile</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>upload2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>costache.examproject.upload2</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>uploadfiles</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>costache.examproject.uploadfiles</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>registrazione</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/registrazione</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>upload</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/upload</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>serve</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/serve</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>caricafile</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/caricafile</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>upload2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/upload2</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>uploadfiles</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/uploadfiles</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>costache</groupId>
    <artifactId>examproject-247809</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>3</version>

    <name>test3</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.82.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.8</version> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
            <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.22</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.64</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Another problem is that Annotations do not work, if I try @MultiPartConfig or @WebServlet they do literally nothing.

Comment: I have the impression that there is something wrong in the pom.xml file. Can you please edit your question and add this as well?

Comment: @siamsot pom.xml added, I added another problem: annotations do not work

Comment: Thanks for adding this. Everything seems fine in your dependencies. I was wondering if you could specify the redirect code with setStatus(307) and also set the header with setHeader("location", location) instead of using the sendRedirect(location) to make sure that the body and the method are not changed during the redirect. Let me know if that worked for you so that I can add it as an answer.